# PHP webform - Getting only attachment name in email not the original attachment

Tags: php, email, webforms, email-attachments

Webform is working fine except the email attachments. I'm getting only the attachment name in email. It should attach the original file in the email. Any help?

Check the below codes & let me know how can I fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'])) 
        {

            $fname=$_POST['fname'];
            $lname=$_POST['lname'];
            $city=$_POST['city'];
            $state=$_POST['state'];
            $country=$_POST['country'];
            $phone=$_POST['phone'];
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $gender=$_POST['gender'];
            $field1=$_POST['field1'];
            $field2=$_POST['field2'];
            $link=$_POST['link'];
            $twit=$_POST['twit'];
            $field3=$_POST['field3'];
            $field4=$_POST['field4'];
            $field5=$_POST['field5'];
            $document1=$_FILES['b_plan']['name'];
            $document2=$_FILES['presentation']['tmp_name'];
            $document3=$_FILES['founder_cvs']['name'];
            //echo $title;
            //echo $document;
            //$path =ABSPATH.'/uploads/applications/'.$_FILES['presentation']['name'];
            //$path =ABSPATH.'/uploads/applications/'.$_FILES['b_plan']['name'];
            $path =ABSPATH.'/uploads/applications/';

            if(isset($_FILES['presentation']['name']))
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['presentation']['tmp_name'], $path.$_FILES['presentation']['name']);
            }
            if(isset($_FILES['founder_cvs']['name']))
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['b_plan']['tmp_name'], $path.$_FILES['b_plan']['name']);
            }
            if(isset($_FILES['founder_cvs']['name']))
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['founder_cvs']['tmp_name'], $path.$_FILES['founder_cvs']['name']);
            }
            //$path =ABSPATH.'wp-content/plugins/document-listing/uploads/'.$_FILES['presentation']['name'];

            //wp-content/plugins/document-listing/uploads/
            //echo $path;
            global $wpdb;
            $n = $wpdb->insert( 
                'wp__form', 
                array( 

                    'first_name' => $fname,
                    'last_name' => $lname,
                    'city' => $city,
                    'state' => $state,
                    'country' => $country,
                    'phone' => $phone,
                    'email'=>$email,
                    'gender'=>$gender,
                    'field1'=>$field1,
                    'field2'=>$field2,
                    'link' => $link,
                    'twit' => $twit,
                    'field3' => $field3,
                    'field4' => $field4,
                    'field5' => $field5,
                    'b_plan' => $document1,
                    'presentation' => $document2,
                    'founder_cvs' =>$document3
                )
            );
                                             $to= "mehreeen786@gmail.com";
                                           //echo $to; die;

                                            $subject=" application on ";

                                            $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['presentation']['tmp_name'])));
                                            $document2 = $_FILES['presentation']['name'];

                                            $body = "
                                                            <p>Dear Admin</p>
                                                            <p>An  application has been received. Please find below the details:</p>
                                                            Title: ".$title."<br/>
                                                            First Name: ".$fname."<br/>
                                                            Last Name: ".$lname."<br/>
                                                            City: ".$city."<br/>
                                                            Emirate/Province: ".$state."<br/>
                                                            Country: ".$country."<br/>
                                                            Phone Number: ".$phone."<br/>
                                                            Email: ".$email."<br/>
                                                            Gender: ".$gender."<br/>
                                                            How did you hear about ?: ".$field1."<br/>
                                                            Company Name: ".$fields2."<br/>
                                                            Management Team (short bios with names, educations, and experience): ".$field3."<br/>
                                                            LinkedIn: ".$link."<br/>
                                                            Twitter: ".$twit."<br/>
                                                            Executive Summary : ".$field4."<br/>
                                                            Anything else you want to add? : ".$field5."<br/>
        Founder CV: ".$document3."<br/>
        Presentation Deck: ".$document2."<br/>
        Financial Projections: ".$document1."<br/>                                                  
                                                            <p>Thanks </p>
                                                            <p> Team </p>   ";  


                                            $headers = 'From: '.$email.''. "\r\n" .
                                                       'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n".
                                                       'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n".
                                                       'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';


                                if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers))
                                {   
                            header('Location:/thankyou/');

                               }

        }


        //echo $msg;
    ?>
```

Comment: does the html form use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: @ Adunahay , yes correct.

Comment: do the files physically show up in the upload dir?

Comment: @ Adunahay, Yes, Files are showing up in the upload dir but not in the email.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not actually attaching anything to your email. You define `$attachment`, but that never gets used anywhere. I would suggest using something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) to make this easier. Once you import PHPMailer, its pretty trivial to attach things:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();

$email->From      = 'you@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = $subject;
$email->Body      = $body;
$email->AddAddress( $to );

$email->AddAttachment( $path . $document2 , $document2 );

$email->Send();
```